# Is it possible to bind to enums with Bond/ReactiveKit? Swift

Tags: swift, enums, swiftbond

I am trying to understand Bond, so I made a test project.
Here I am using a class chocolate

```
class Chocolate {
    var brandname: String = ""
    var type: ChocolateType = .crunchy
}
```

and a enum ChocolateType with rawValues

```
enum ChocolateType: String {
    case crunchy = "crunchy"
    case nougat = "nougat"
    case dark = "dark"
    case white = "white"
    case nuts = "nuts"
}
```

Is there any way, that I can bind a lable or another UIObject to the ChocolateType, so that'll update with the text = label.text?

Favorably I would like to give a ViewController just the chocolate from the ViewModel and let the bindings do the rest.

What changes do I have to make?